# Google maps event listener dragend

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, dom-events

I am adding an event listener to my marker, the function for the marker is:

```js
function setupMarkerWaypoint() {
  console.log('setting waypoint marker');
  waypointMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: default_latlng,
    map: mapBooking,
    icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png"
  });

  waypointMarker.setVisible(true);

  function geocodePosition(pos) {
    geocoder.geocode({
      'latLng': pos
    }, function(responses) {
      if (responses && responses.length > 0) {
        updateMarkerAddress(responses[0].formatted_address);
      } else {
        updateMarkerAddress('Cannot determine address at this location.');
      }
    });
  }

  function updateMarkerAddress(str) {
    document.getElementById('AddWaypoint').innerHTML = str;
  }

  // Update current position info.

  geocodePosition(latLng);

  // Add dragging event listeners.

  google.maps.event.addListener(waypointMarker, 'dragend', function() {
    updateMarkerStatus('Drag ended');
    geocodePosition(waypointMarker.getPosition());
  });

}
```

But I am unable to drag my marker on google maps. what necessary changes should I make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the marker draggable, set its `draggable` property to `true`.

[Google Maps Javascript API Reference: MarkerOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions)

```
waypointMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: default_latlng,
    map: mapBooking,
    draggable: true,
    icon:"http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png"
});
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/x17pstmh/1/)

code snippet:

```js
var geocoder;
var mapBooking;
var default_latlng

function initialize() {
  mapBooking = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  default_latlng = mapBooking.getCenter();
  setupMarkerWaypoint();

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

function setupMarkerWaypoint() {
  console.log('setting waypoint marker');
  waypointMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: default_latlng,
    map: mapBooking,
    draggable: true,
    icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png"
  });

  waypointMarker.setVisible(true);

  function geocodePosition(pos) {
    geocoder.geocode({
      'latLng': pos
    }, function(responses) {
      if (responses && responses.length > 0) {
        updateMarkerAddress(responses[0].formatted_address);
      } else {
        updateMarkerAddress('Cannot determine address at this location.');
      }
    });
  }

  function updateMarkerAddress(str) {
    document.getElementById('AddWaypoint').innerHTML = str;
  }

  // Update current position info.

  geocodePosition(waypointMarker.getPosition());

  // Add dragging event listeners.

  google.maps.event.addListener(waypointMarker, 'dragend', function() {
    // updateMarkerStatus('Drag ended');
    geocodePosition(waypointMarker.getPosition());
  });

}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,places"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
<div id="AddWaypoint"></div>
```

Comment: I would like to geocode for dragend(google event listener), similar to this example https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple. But my address key states undefined. Any inputs ?

Comment: Sounds like a new question.  I have done that in the past.  Actually, what address? You should be using the reverse geocoder, which takes the coordinates.

Comment: Here's the example link http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_geocoding-reversegeocoding-simple.html. I have worked the event listener part -geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
   console.log(results);
   if (results[0]) {
    var formatted_address = results[0].formatted_address;
    
    infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);                                                                I get an error 'latlng' : undefined

Comment: Please ask another question.  Comments are not for new questions and code posted in the comments is really hard to read.